# Rails caching with user specific button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, memcached

This is my first rails app and I am now trying to optimize and cache appropriately and it can be a little daunting at first.

Whenever `Programs` are listed, if the `User` is the creator of that `Program` it shows an "Edit Program" Button. Otherwise, nothing is displayed.

The program list will not change that often (maybe a couple times a day?) What is the best way to cache this?

It seems like it would be wrong to do a fragment cache for each user/program relationship, because it is just a single `User` who will see that button.

Or do I simply need to redesign my view to ignore this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest doing a cache key that is based on both the program as well as a method like, program.owned_by(user).

For example, the view might be something like this

```
<% cache [program.cache_key, program.owned_by?(user)] do %>
  # all of your view code here
<% end %>
```

What this will do is create fragment cache not only on the program but whether or not the thing is owned by the user object. program.cache_key will be based on the programs updated_at timestamp so it should expire when necessary. The second part of this compound cache key would essentially be true or false based on whether or not the program is owned by the user. You would have to implement that method in your model.

Hope this helps.